# PropertyGrid & Object Property: Category

Tags: c#, propertygrid

I'm working on a project that involves viewing and changing the
properties of a class element with the PropertyGrid control. The
properties of the class element are references to other objects
(themselves) have properties.

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public abstract class Elemento
{  
   ....

   [CategoryAttribute("Materiale Associato 1"), DescriptionAttribute("Caratteristiche standard del Materiale 1")]
   public Standard1 Standard1 {get;set;}

   [CategoryAttribute("Materiale Associato 2"), DescriptionAttribute("Caratteristiche standard del Materiale 2")]
   public Standard2 Standard2 {get;set;}
}
```

This object will passed to the SelectedObject property (PropertyGrid).
I would like to divide the properties of the class Standard1 (and Standard2)  into
categories. I tried to decorate the properties in this way:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(Standard1Converter))]
public class Standard1
{  
   [CategoryAttribute("Property1")]
   public AnObject Property {get;set;}

   [CategoryAttribute("Property2"), DescriptionAttribute("A property")]
   public AnObject Property2 {get;set;}
```

but the properties are not grouped. I see only the description. What is wrong?

NB: Standard1Converter : ExpandableObjectConverter

Comment: What do you mean by "he properties are not grouped". What do you expect exactly?

Comment: When i select an Elemento, i see (in propertyGrid) the property (as a Standard1) grouped by categories, but when i "expand" the object Standard1, the relative property, are not categorized. sorry for my bad english!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no subcategories in the standard MS PropertyGrid. This means that only the top level object passed to SelectedObject will be categorized.